# C++ glDrawElements Array as Parameter EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl-es

I got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error at the glDrawElements call. I think there is something wrong with the array passed to the Shape constructor. What could be the problem here.

main.cpp

```
static const GLfloat cube_vertices[] = {
   -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
   1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
   -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
   1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
   -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
   1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
   -1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
   1.0,  1.0, -1.0,
};

static const GLushort indices[] = {
    0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 1, 5, 4, 7, 6, 2, 4, 0, 1
};

cube = new Shape(shader, cube_vertices, 3 * 8, indices, 14);
```

Shape.h

```
const GLushort *indices;
```

Shape.cpp

```
Shape::Shape(Shader* cshader, const GLfloat *vertices, int size, const GLushort *cindices, int indSize) :  {
indices = cindices;
}
```

Render method

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 14, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
```

As I said here is the problem. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are passing GL_TRIANGLES then your index buffer length should be a multiple of 3 (i.e. every 3 index values forms one triangle).

Other than that what you have posted looks OK - so we'll need a more complete test case to be able to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I found a different way. I used different vertices and indices and GL_TRIANGLE_STRIPS. Furthermore I left out the "indices" in the draw call and set it to 0. Now it draws.